# Recursive Function with Callback JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, functional-programming

I have these two recursive functions.  The top one works but the when I try to make the `quantityColumn` function as a `callback` to second function, I get an error that `callback is not a function`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
var sumColumn = function(lineNumber) {
    return lineNumber === 0 
        ? quantityColumn(0)
        : quantityColumn(lineNumber) + sumColumn(lineNumber -1)
}

sumColumn(lineCount) // returns 9 

var sumColumn = function(callback, lineNumber) {
    return lineNumber === 0 
        ? callback(0)
        : callback(lineNumber) + sumColumn(callback(lineNumber -1), lineNumber -1)
}
sumColumn(quantityColumn, lineCount) // callback is not a function
```

In case more code is required. Here is what the `quantityColumn` function is. Also of note, `current.getSublistValue` is a 3rd party API (NetSuite) that basically just returns the of the intersections of a line/row on a table.

```
 var columnValue = R.curry(function(getSublistValue, sublistId, column, i) {
     return getSublistValue({
         sublistId: sublistId,
         fieldId: column,
         line: i              
      })
   }
)
var itemSublist(current.getSublistValue)('item')
var quantityColumn = itemSublist('quantity')
var lineCount = current.getLineCount('item') - 1 // first index is 0

quantityColumn(5) // 2
quantityColumn(4) // 1
quantityColumn(3) ...

var sumColumn = function(lineNumber) {
    return lineNumber === 0 
        ? quantityColumn(0)
        : quantityColumn(lineNumber) + sumColumn(lineNumber -1)
}
sumColumn(lineCount) // returns 9
```

Comment: as you can see `var sumColumn = function(callback, lineNumber) ` expect parameter 1 to be ` callback` (and you need two arguments to call the function properly).You are calling the function `sumColumn(lineCount)` and it goes right into `callback` (lineCount->callback) , not(lineCount->lineNumber)

Comment: What does `var itemSublist(current.getSublistValue)('item')` mean?

Comment: I had my example wrong, I did call it that way. `itemSublist(current.getSublistValue)('item')` is just created a `partial application` of the function.  They are just values necessary to execute the 3rd party API `getSublistValue`.  There could be other "sublist" tables is why it is useful to have it curried like this

Comment: `itemSublist('quantity')` Returns a `function` right? and `quantityColumn(5) // 2` work too?

Comment: correct and correct @Anandhu

Comment: please check out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sumColumn = function(lineNumber) {
    return lineNumber === 0 
        ? quantityColumn(0)
        : quantityColumn(lineNumber) + sumColumn(lineNumber -1)
}

sumColumn(lineCount) // returns 9 

var sumColumn = function(callback, lineNumber) {
    return lineNumber === 0 
        ? callback(0)
        : callback(lineNumber) + sumColumn(callback, lineNumber -1)
}
sumColumn(quantityColumn, lineCount) // callback is not a function
```

In this line `callback(lineNumber) + sumColumn(callback(lineNumber -1), lineNumber -1)` You are calling the function `callback` (with arguments lineNumber-1) what you want is to pass it along

Comment: Ah I see, I just need to pass the `callback` itself into the recursive call. Thanks @Anandu!  I tested in environment and it worked.